# "who is alive" vs. "alive" / "who is angry" vs. "angry"

Tags: grammar

Can you omit "who is" from the following sentences:

1) "There's a man who is alive."

Reduced Form: "There's a man alive."

2) "There's a man who is angry."

Reduced Form: "There's a man angry."

If not, why?

Comment: What is wrong with *"There's a living man"* and *"There's an angry man"*?

Comment: 'Alive' and 'angry' are not grammatical equivalents despite both being adjectives. [Alive - OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/5093?rskey=149XtH&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) : As an intensifier, esp. following a superlative or an inclusive or exclusive expression, as any man alive, etc..

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650) says that of Whiz deletion that, if there is just a single adjective left, it goes before the noun. So the result of Whiz deletion in your examples is "There's an alive man" and "There's an angry man".

The second of these is normal. The first is odd, because "alive" is not usually used attributively, but only predicatively.

Comment: The slightly irregular whiz deletion that works is, "There's a live man".

Comment: Has it been like that since time immemorial?

Answer (score 1):

Angry follows the majority of adjectives being found in the attributive position.

> A man who is angry is an angry man.

But in answer to your question 'alive' follows the noun.

> There's still a man alive down there!

The predicative positon of alive is related to the history of a group of adjectives beginning with 'a' which were originally prepositional phrases and have kept their old sentence position.

Etymonline

[a- (1)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/a-)

> prefix or inseparable particle, a relic of various Germanic and Latin
>   elements.
>
> In words derived from Old English, it commonly represents Old English
>   an "on, in, into" (see on (prep.)), as in alive, above, asleep, aback,
>   abroad, afoot, ashore, ahead, abed, aside, etc., forming adjectives
>   and adverbs from nouns, with the notion "in, at; engaged in." In this
>   use it is identical to a (2).

And here an extract from the Etymonline entry for

[alive](https://www.etymonline.com/word/alive#etymonline_v_8161) (adj.)

> c. 1200, "in life, living," contraction of Old English on life "in
>   living, not dead," from a- (1) + dative of *lif* "life" (see life). The
>   full form on live was still current 17c.